# [Homework Question]What is the Authorization Grant in OAuth?

Tags: rest, api, oauth

Question:

```
In OAuth the Authorization Grant:  
  (a). is a token accompanying the request to access the customer information;  
  (b). can be used multiple times until the expiry is reached;  
  (c). is a token generated when the customer agree to authorize access to the data;
```

I will answer the question below, please anyone point out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I made the answer according to the following picture:
 (a) is **wrong** because Authorisation Grant is a token that sends back to the server in step 2.
(but can we consider it's true due to the server B send the request with it to server A at step3?)
  (b) is **wrong** since the Oauth can only use for one time or it will not safe anymore;
(c) is **correct**: we can look at the pic below, B sends a request to access the client data to client at step1, and the client agrees then response with an Authorisation Grant(token) at step 2.

As you see, I have a little confusion at (a), please give me some advice if anyone would like to help! Thanks!

[image]